# Angular 2 web socket

Tags: angular, websocket

I need develop a part of my app in realtime. I'm using Django with Django Rest Framework in my backend and Angular 2 (final release) in my frontend.

I'm not sure if is needed to use a web socket or if a webhook also is correct. I have an hours list to be reserved by mi **user A**. While this user is looking for an specific hour to reserve, the user B can select an hour, and I wish block the hour that **user B** select to the **user A**.

I really do not know where to start. What exist in Angular 2 to help me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Long story short, because your question is too broad for this site: if you want to "push" something from server to client without being actually responding to a request from the client to the server, which seems to be the case, websockets are your solution.

Comment: -1.... I think this is clearly explained. **What exist in Angular 2 to help me to do this?** Obviusly is web socket, but what is the best solution (package, libraries, workflow, etc) in angular 2 with django and django rest framework